# How to read two matrices from a single input file in Python

Tags: python, io

I have saved two matrices A and B as below in a single .txt file.

Matrix A:

2,4,5

4,7,3

---

Matrix B:

1,2

5,9

1,6

In Python, how can I read the two matrices A and B separately from this input file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file looks something like this (The matrices are seperated by an empty line):

```
2,4,5
4,7,3

1,2
5,9
1,6
```

This python code (for python3):

```
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
a = []
b = []
current = a # Current will point to the current matrix

for line in input_file.readlines():
    if ',' not in line: # This is our separator - a line with no ',', switch a matrix
        current = b
    else:
        current.append([]) # Add a row to our current matrix
        for x in line.split(','): # Values are separated by ','
            current[len(current) - 1].append(int(x)) # Add int(x) to the last line

print(a, b)
input_file.close()
```

Outputs the following:

```
[[2, 4, 5], [4, 7, 3]] [[1, 2], [5, 9], [1, 6]]
```

Comment: It is showing the error message: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '  \n' "

Comment: It seems your matrices are separated by a ' \n', not '\n' - which is not an empty line, but a line with a space. I edited the answer so that it uses a line without ',' to separate the matrices. It should work now, please try it again.